# How to use c++20 modules with GCC?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm currently trying the new C++20's feature called **modules** as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) using GCC 10.1.0, however if i try to build the following snippet of code the compiler throw me a bunch of errors.

This is the snippets i wrote so far:

```cpp
// helloworld.cpp
export module helloworld;  // module declaration
import <iostream>;         // import declaration
 
export void hello() {      // export declaration
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
import helloworld;  // import declaration
 
int main() {
    hello();
}
```

I'm compiling it using `g++ helloworld.cpp main.cpp -std=c++20`.

The compiler gave me this error:

```
helloworld.cpp:2:1: warning: keyword ‘export’ not implemented, and will be ignored
    2 | export module helloworld;  // module declaration
      | ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:2:8: error: ‘module’ does not name a type
    2 | export module helloworld;  // module declaration
      |        ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
    3 | import <iostream>;         // import declaration
      |         ^~~~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:9: error: ‘iostream’ was not declared in this scope
helloworld.cpp:3:1: error: ‘import’ does not name a type
    3 | import <iostream>;         // import declaration
      | ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:5:1: warning: keyword ‘export’ not implemented, and will be ignored
    5 | export void hello() {      // export declaration
      | ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp: In function ‘void hello()’:
helloworld.cpp:6:10: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
    6 |     std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
      |          ^~~~
helloworld.cpp:1:1: note: ‘std::cout’ is defined in header ‘<iostream>’; did you forget to ‘#include <iostream>’?
  +++ |+#include <iostream>
    1 | // helloworld.cpp
main.cpp:2:1: error: ‘import’ does not name a type
    2 | import helloworld;  // import declaration
      | ^~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:5: error: ‘hello’ was not declared in this scope
    5 |     hello();
      |     ^~~~~
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[GCC's language status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) says it doesn't support modules yet.

C++20 support is not complete (which is fair enough given that we're *in* 2020! And C++20 technically doesn't exist yet…).

However, with some flags and a development branch you can play around with the in-progress implementation — read more about it on [GCC's Modules Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules).

The default language version in GCC 10 is C++14; GCC 11 ups that to C++17.

Comment: Four years after, maybe this post needs an update ?

Answer (score 15):

I saw the GNU gcc website as of 23.1.21 and it says u have to include a flag called -fmodules-ts . Here is the link for the website for additional info
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules

Answer (score 5):

For now, if you use GCC, done with:

```
# g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts hello.cpp -o hello.exe -x c++-system-header iostream
```

Comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73643558/19946116

And if you prefer Visual studio 2022, you need configure it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73643523/19946116.

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile the `iostream` module first:

```bash
g++ -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header iostream
```

It will generate a local folder named `gcm.cache` in your current working directory.

Now, you can compile your code (the -fmodules-ts option is still needed):

```bash
g++ -fmodules-ts helloworld.cpp main.cpp -o hello
```

Reference: [C++ Modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

With your two sources the better way to do is

`g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts hello-m.cpp main.cpp -o hello -xc++-system-header iostream`

using GCC 12.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If using CLion, in "cmake-build-debug" folder should use this cmd to generate "gcm.cache" folder:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header iostream
```

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhkrU.png)

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyE73.png)

Then write code like this:

"CMakeLists.txt":

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts")

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)
```

"main.cpp":

```
import <iostream>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```