# How can I benefit from LTO in my library without requiring it of applications?

Tags: c++, lto

I'm developing a library with lots of object files with functions that call each other. I'd like for these functions to benefit from the cross-object-file optimizations enabled by LTO, but without requiring applications that use my library to themselves link with LTO.

Is such a thing possible?

I have already moved some function definitions to headers where practical. A unity build would be problematic because of heavy use of anonymous namespaces and file scope statics.

Once again, my goal is for LTO to occur at library creation time. **Not** when applications link my library.

I'm on Linux with GCC, but clang is available to me.

Comment: Are you making a static library, or a dynamic library?

Comment: A static library. What are the consequences of trying this with a shared library?

Comment: I don't think a static library can take advantage of LTO, because the LTO (as I understand it, and I don't have deep knowledge thereof) happens at link time.  A static library is more like a ZIP file of object code (an *archive* (**.a**) of object files (**.o**)).  A shared library is linked, so there it may be able to take advantage of LTO.  (Caveats on my lack of experience with LTO.)

Comment: I understand that static libraries are just a bag of object files. But is there some way to use a compiler's LTO machinery to compile each .o as if every other .o was available for inlining, constant propagation, and all the other optimization goodness, but without running into problems with ODR and all the anonymous static stuff? Is there something fundamental about LTO that makes this impossible, or has this use case just not been considered?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken... the LTO machinery can be used at *link-time*, but the creation of the static library is before link-time.  For LTO to work, it has to have all the pieces available in order to do a wholistic optimization.  Creating a static library doesn't have all the pieces yet.

Comment: You might want to have a peek at GCC's implementation of C++20 modules. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765630/how-to-use-c20-modules-with-gcc/62765649

Answer (score 1):

The gcc option `-flinker-output=rel`[[1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)] might give you something like what you want. You'd use it to run the linker on your library, doing all the LTO stuff in the scope of your library, and then spit out an object file. To turn this back into a static library you could run `ar` on it [[2](https://www.howtogeek.com/427086/how-to-use-linuxs-ar-command-to-create-static-libraries/)].
I haven't done this myself though and I think the [unity build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636019/506073) is the better option.

1. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html
2. https://www.howtogeek.com/427086/how-to-use-linuxs-ar-command-to-create-static-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

To benefit from the same optimisations as LTO of a static library would theoretically enable, give your library a **unity build** option.
This uses one source file which includes all other code in the library into a single translation unit where it is subject to the same whole-library inter-procedural analysis that you are looking for. SQLite is an example of a widely used library using this approach, even distributing itself as a single source file which is the result of all these transitive inclusions pre-processed into the [SQLite Amalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html). Modern CMake [supports unity builds](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/UNITY_BUILD.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What happens to all of my anonymous namespaces that define symbols with common names?

Comment: They need to all be revised to have unique names. Sorry that my answer ignored this problem raised in your question.