# How do I import C++ 20 <format> module?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am using Visual Studio 2019 (Community edition) running on a Windows 10 machine. I have created a simple console application and I want to import the format module so that I can use something like std::format(). I get an error that 'cannot find header 'format' to import. My code is based on a book by Horton and van Weet titled 'Beginning C++ 20' which starts with two lines namely: import iostream (this is contained in angled brackets) followed by a line which says import format also contained within angled brackets. Maybe let me rephrase my question. The code generated by Visual Studio says #include iostream but does not allow me to #include format. So, when do I use #include and when do I use import?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Does VS implement `std::format` yet?

Comment: @NicolBolas Don't think it does, no, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160 (and search the page for `<format>`).

Comment: What does the `__cpp_lib_format` C++ feature flag result in?  (q.v. [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).)

Comment: afaik `<format>` is supported only since 16.10 which is currently still a preview release: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/wiki/Changelog#vs-2019-1610-preview-3

Comment: There's also the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which has very similar features to the version adopted in C++20, it's a small library available through vcpkg.

Comment: Does that book also mention how did they compile their examples?

Comment: Unfortunately the book (published by apress.com and 815 pages long) simply states the compilers that one can choose from - GCC and Clang, Code::Blocks, Qt creator and Microsoft Visual C++ IDE.

Comment: You can try the 16.10 Preview 3, or wait until it gets officially released; but it's not available in 16.9 or below.

Comment: @Khandakhulu, VS 16.10 is now released, so you can try updating to that. Should work with `/std:latest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for MSVS support of std::format, you can use the fmt library that is the basis for the std::format. This can be found at https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt. It is compatible with the C++20 standard but does include additional features. Add the library to your source and use fmt::format instead of std::format. It'll be easy to convert this to std::format once fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio 2019/2022 to run C++20 code, you need go to: Project->'source code name' Properties and:

1. Configuration Properities->General->C++ Lanaguage Standard: **ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)**.
2. Configuration Properities->C/C++->Language->C++ Lanaguage Standard: **ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)**.
3. Configuration Properities->C/C++ ->General -> Scan Sources for Module Dependencies: **Yes**.

These three options **must** be done.

Comment: Two links maybe useful.
https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/283863/

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-c7612-could-not-find-header-unit/1347013