# How to import modules using gcc/g++ 11.1

Tags: c++, gcc, module, g++, c++20

Not sure if `import <module_Name>;` is supported right now. When I try to run a program including modules it stats `note: c++20 'import' only available with '-fmodules-ts'` is that a compiler flag like `-std=c++20` or are modules not currently supported. Here is an example program using modules:

```
#include<iostream>
import <numbers>;
import <format>;

int main()
{
    double pi {std::numbers::pi};
    std::cout << std::format("Pi is = to {}", pi);

}
```

I understand I can use `#include <numbers>` but I'm trying to figure out if modules work. I'm not so sure if `<import>` can be added using `#include`.

**EDIT 10/8/21:**
I made a secondary program removing `<format>` and `std::format()` to test the implementation of `import <numbers>;` using the `-fmodules-ts` flag and it still didnt work. See program and terminal below.

program:

```
#include<iostream>
import <numbers>;


int main()
{
    double pi {std::numbers::pi};
    std::cout << pi;
}
```

Terminal:

```
g++ randomCodeWhileReading.cpp -o main -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts
randomCodeWhileReading.cpp:2:1: error: unknown Compiled Module Interface: no such module
    2 | import <numbers>;
      | ^~~~~~
In module imported at randomCodeWhileReading.cpp:2:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/numbers: error: failed to read compiled module: Unknown CMI mapping
/usr/include/c++/11/numbers: note: imports must be built before being imported
/usr/include/c++/11/numbers: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: @sweenish the flag didn't work that is why I posted I assumed I misinterpreted. i'm not sure if <format> is supported as of gcc/g++ 11.1 so I ran an example using just numbers . See edit.

Comment: try `g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c -x c++-system-header numbers`. You first need to compile the header to produce CMI/BMI (manually). Unfortunately g++ doesn't yet support string formatting library.

Comment: @DesmondGold I'm new to this so i'm sort of confused on how to use that. Your saying I have to run the command you suggested to compile the header first then after that I run a second command to open the code & compile? such as 'g++ randomCodeWhileRunning.cpp -o main -std=c++2a' (would I still need '-fmodules-ts' ? ) . Thanks for helping a noob out lol

Comment: @DesmondGold your comment is helpful. Consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ExZerminator, you are right. Done with:

```
# g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts hello.cpp -o hello.exe -x c++-system-header iostream
```